# How to get the color coded plotted areas in images using R?

Tags: r, pixel, area, spatstat

Hi R expert of the world, 
Assume I have a point pattern that generate an intensity map and that this map is color coded in 3 region in an pixeled image.... how could I get the color-coded area?

here it is an example using spatstat:

```
library(spatstat)
japanesepines
Z<-density(japanesepines); plot(dens) # ---> I create a density map
b <- quantile(Z, probs = (0:3)/3) # ---> I "reduce it" to 3 color-ceded zones
Zcut <- cut(Z, breaks = b, labels = 1:3); plot(Zcut)
class(Zcut) # ---> and Zcut is my resultant image ("im")
```

Thank you in advance
Sacc

Comment: I actually want to calculate the pixel area of each color

Answer (score 1):

In your specific example it is very easy to calculate the area because you used `quantile` to cut the image: This effectively divides the image into areas of equal size, so there should be three areas of size 1/3 since the window is a unit square. In general to calculate areas from a factor valued image you could use `as.tess` and `tile.areas` (continuing your example):

```
Ztess <- as.tess(Zcut)
tile.areas(Ztess)
```

In this case the areas are 0.333313, which must be due to discretization.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not exactly sure what you're after, but you can count up the number of pixels in each color using the `table()` function.

```
table(Zcut[[1]])
```